# Reading from a .in file in c

Tags: c, while-loop

I have been coding this c file that reads in exactly 2 integers of a line of a .in file. So far, my code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void divideTwoNums()
{
    int c = 0;
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    int product = 0;
    c = getchar();

    while (c != '\n' && c != ' ' && c != '\t')
    {
        num1 = 10 * num1 + (c - '0');
        c = getchar();
    }
    c = getchar();
    while (c != '\n' && c != ' ' && c != '\t')
    {
        num2 = 10 * num2 + (c - '0');
        c = getchar();
    }
    product = num1 / num2;
    printf("%d / %d = %d\n", num1, num2, product);
}
int main(void)
{
    divideTwoNums();
    return 0;
}
```

When I try this code on a .in file like this:

```
96 16
```

My .out file reads like this:

```
96 / 16 = 6
```

So, I know I am doing something right because the code worked for one line. However, I am stuck when it comes to multiple lines. Let's say my .in file reads like this:

```
96 16
50 10
```

My code won't work because I do not have a while loop, within the divideTwoNums method, that helps me get to a next sentence. Now, I tried various stuff but they were to no avail. Can you guys help me out?

edit:

[image: Screenshot of the code for R Sahu]

Comment: "I tried various stuff"  Like what?  show us what things you tried, so we can help you figure out what went wrong.  This should be a very simple problem to solve, simply by wrapping the code inside another loop that checks for `!EOF`.....

Comment: I don't see any file IO operations. Sure you posted the correct code?

Comment: Okay @Claies, so I put the code from the first while loop until the printf statement within a while loop which reads as:    while (c != EOF) and when that did not work, I tried    while (c !=  '\n') but to no avail.

Comment: Don't post screenshots of text. You can't paste a screenshot into an editor for playing.

Comment: Please don't post screen shots of code — it is unreadable (especially on mobile devices), and uncopyable (so it can't be tested, modified, etc).

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of issues you need to deal with:

1. Using a loop to divide the numbers for more lines.
2. Figuring out when to exit the loop, i.e. detecting when there is no more input.

You can accomplish the first one by using a `while` loop in `main`.

```
int main(void)
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
       divideTwoNums();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

To detect that there is no input, you have do couple of things.

1. Check the return value of `getchar()`. If the return value is EOF, there is no more input.
2. Return a value from `divideTwoNums()` to indicate that there is no more input.

Here's a skeletal update to the function. I am assuming you can complete the rest.

```
// The return value needs to be int instead of void.
int divideTwoNums()
{
   ...

   c = getchar();
   if ( c == EOF )
   {
      // Return 0 to indicate to stop the loop.
      return 0;
   }

   ...

   // Return 1 to indicate to continue with the loop.
   return 1;
}
```

and change `main` to:

```
int main(void)
{
    int cont = 1;
    while ( cont )
    {
       cont = divideTwoNums();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you man for the help! One question, I got a 'floating point exception (core dumped)' after I implemented your solution. Being new to C, i couldn't figure out from other relevant Stack Overflow threads that have discussed this problem. What do you think I should do?

Comment: Also, I will edit my thread to include a screenshot which is a confirmation that I have done what you suggested me to do.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)  might help.